# Matlab: Indexing multidimensional array with a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing, vectorization

I have a three dimensional matrix named *Spr* of size *5x5x500*. The last dimension represents individuals while the first two dimensions refer to states. Hence, for each individual, I am storing a 5x5 matrix of transition probabilities from state i to state j. For instance, the last individual's transition probabilities are:

```
Spr( : , : , 500)
```

ans =

```
0.1386    0.3768    0.2286    0.1871    0.0688
0.1456    0.3959    0.2401    0.1966    0.0218
0.1475    0.4011    0.2433    0.1992    0.0090
0.1486    0.4039    0.2450    0.2006    0.0020
     0    1.0000         0         0         0
```

I would like to access the three dimensional matrix Spr with the first index being provided by a 500x1 matrix S which stores in which state the specific individual is currently in. Hence, my final result would be a 1x5x500 matrix. For instance, if the 500th individual is currently in state S(i)=2 the corresponding row for this individual would correspond to:

```
Spr(S(i),:,i)

0.1456    0.3959    0.2401    0.1966    0.0218
```

How can I do that without using loops?

I've tried using the *sub2ind* function in Matlab but it doesn't work as it requires all the indexes be integers and essentially my second index is the character *":"* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to fullfill the "no loops" requirement:

```
N=sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(full(sparse(S,1:numel(S),1)),[1,3,2]),Spr),1)
```

The trick is to build up a indexing matrix which selects the right content using `times`.
This solution is okay, but I don't like it because it's slower and less memory efficient than this much simpler solution using a for loop:

```
N=nan(1,size(Spr,2),size(Spr,3))
for k=1:size(Spr,1)
    N(1,:,S==k)=Spr(k,:,S==k)
end
```

Comment: Indeed the for loop seems much simpler. I need to embed this operation within another for loop and I was afraid that it would be very time consuming having nested loops. Thank you!